# how to connect ms sql database from one computer to the other?

Tags: sql-server

I have a computer(computer A) which the ms sql installed, and I have another computer(Computer B) in which the application resides. I want to connect the ms sql database from computer B to computer using this application?How will I do that? What is the connection string should I use, firewall settings, database configutions, etc?

Comment: [http://www.connectionstrings.com/](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) is a good place to start for the connection string portion of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, firewall rules will have to open up port 1433 by default. That can change (but has little reason to), but if you're running just one instance and didn't change this, it's likely 1433.

Enable remote connections through sql studio and TCP/IP through connection manager: 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1338911.aspx/1?how+to+enable+remote+Connection+sql+server+2008

And Joe Stefanelli's excellent connection strings site, www.connectionstrings.com; different application languages/tech will use different connection strings.

You'll also need a user of some sort, and whatever authtype. Easiest would be sql server auth, and that would be as easy as right clicking on the "security" folder under a database in management studio, and going new->user

Hope that helps!